# How to update android app without user interaction?

Tags: auto-update, android, android-applicationinfo

I am developing an application in android, i just want to add feature of auto update when the internet is available. I want to update app while app is running as well as when the app not in active mode.
Please reply me with any idea.

Comment: if you want to download and install new APK without user interaction, then it's imposible. This is equal to downloading and installing the application without user confirmation. If it would be posible, then it  was a grait security bug.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to put app to android market, autoupdate will be there automagically.

Comment: you sound clueless basically